# changing two dimensional array elements

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

```
white_board=[[]]
for x in range(100):
    white_board[0].append(0)
for x in range(99):
    white_board.append(white_board[0]) #100*100 0 two dimensional array
n=int(input())
posL=[] #dot's position List
for x in range(n):
    a,b=map(int,input().split())
    posL.append((a,b))
for y in posL:
    indY=100-y[1]
    for z in range(10):
        indX=y[0]-1
        for h in range(10):
            if white_board[indY][indX]==0:
                white_board[indY][indX]=1
            indX+=1
        indY-=1
```

(i'm trying to solve this problem https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/2563)
i tried this code, but on procedure changing elements, it changes all list's elements.
ex input)
3
3 7
15 7
5 2

on 3 7 case, it changes all white_board list's 3rd index to 1

how to solve this problem?

i think managing indexs is problem.....

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you need to create separate lists for each row.

```
white_board = [[0] * 100 for _ in range(100)]

n = int(input())
posL = []  # dot's position List

for _ in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    posL.append((a, b))

for y in posL:
    indY = 100 - y[1]
    for _ in range(10):
        indX = y[0] - 1
        for _ in range(10):
            if white_board[indY][indX] == 0:
                white_board[indY][indX] = 1
            indX += 1
        indY -= 1

total_inked_area = sum(row.count(1) for row in white_board)
print(total_inked_area)
```